# python datetime strptime and strftime grouped and sort

Tags: python, sorting, datetime, strftime, strptime

I want to sort these by dates:

```
    2013-11-Wednesday 10    93005
    2013-07-Wednesday 18    143009
    2013-07-Wednesday 19    154074
    2013-07-Wednesday 16    86113
    2013-07-Wednesday 17    109588
    2013-09-Thursday 20 124705
    2013-09-Saturday 21 99999
    2013-12-Wednesday 09    85503
    2013-10-Tuesday 22  133288
    2013-10-Tuesday 23  103780
    2013-10-Tuesday 20  151353
    2013-10-Tuesday 21  147596
    2013-09-Saturday 20 101429
    2013-06-Tuesday 07  88275
    2013-12-Saturday 14 100049
    2013-12-Saturday 15 96757
    2013-12-Saturday 12 102583
    2013-12-Saturday 13 104355
    2013-12-Saturday 10 83527
    2013-06-Tuesday 06  47676
    2013-06-Tuesday 05  17941
    2013-12-Saturday 18 101733
    2013-12-Saturday 19 103355
```

I first used strptime to see what it produces so that I can sort based on that

```
2013-12-Tuesday 23
2013-12-01 23:00:00
Sunday

2013-12-Wednesday 00
2013-12-01 00:00:00
Sunday
```

As you can see,datetime.strptime(k, "%Y-%m-%A %H") and datetime.strftime(datetime.strptime(k, "%Y-%m-%A %H"), "%A")
both produce the same result for different k.

Input is days of the month and time. 
e.g. Tuesdays in December at 23
Wednesdays in December at 00

What is proper way to fix this code?

```
 for k,v in sorted(newDay.iteritems()):
    print k
    print datetime.strptime(k, "%Y-%m-%A %H")
    print datetime.strftime(datetime.strptime(k, "%Y-%m-%A %H"), "%A")
    print ""
```

Comment: So these are *all* those weekdays in a given month? `2013-12-Tuesday` represents 5 different dates?

Comment: Yes, grouped by the days of week.  All Tuesdays in December at 23, All Wednesday in December at 00

Comment: The `%A` token won't get you those dates; without at least a week number *Tuesday* is ambiguous, so no day of the month is set and you get the 1st of the month. Are you looking for code to produce all those weekdays for a given month instead?

Comment: Final goal is to plot where y will be the count and the x will be Mondays of January at 00 through Sundays of December at 24

Comment: Martijin, the input is grouped by weekdays from counting dates like 2013-12-07 02. What should be the proper way to sort for the given input above or is it impossible to sort unless I change the format of input.

Comment: I'm just still not clear as to what you mean by *grouped by weekdays* here, so I moved on.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear.  How would you sort the given input above?